# SQL Select query to group into 'Other' section

Tags: sql

This is the query I have:

```
SELECT country, COUNT(country) AS total FROM Employees GROUP BY country ORDER BY total ASC
```

And the results are like follow:

```
country| total
=============
US     | 100
CA     | 80
GB     | 60
GE     | 50
SI     | 30
...
SK     | 9
PO     | 5
SA     | 4
LX     | 2
...
```

I would like modify my SELECT query so that I am able to group all the countries that have for example less than 10 total into a single row like this:

```
country| total
=============
US     | 100
CA     | 80
GB     | 60
GE     | 50
SI     | 30
...
Other  | 45
```

Feel free to edit my question if it is not clear enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with nested aggregations:

```
SELECT (case when total > 10 then country else 'other' end) as country,
       sum(total) as total
FROM (SELECT country, COUNT(country) AS total
      FROM Employees
      GROUP BY country
     ) eg
GROUP BY (case when total > 10 then country else 'other' end)
ORDER BY total ASC;
```

Comment: in `mysql` you can use `GROUP BY country` instead of `GROUP BY (CAS...`

Comment: @MajidTaheri . . . True.  But the question is not tagged MySQL and that does not work in all databases.